# Apache HttpClient for making Elastic Search Requests incorrect results

Tags: elasticsearch, httpclient

I am making Elastic Search Requests using Apache HttpClient and the response is always zero results. How ever when i execute the same Query using Kibana i am getting the accurate results.

Here is the search Query i am using in Kibana.

```
GET my_index_name*/_search 
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match" : {
            "hashCode" : "7c9abf19382064fc8cea2833f4663df9813e72273ecacc8c67b5608dda1ccbab"

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

And the Response i am getting is

```
{
  "took": 45,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 440,
    "successful": 440,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 2.4277482,
    "hits": [...]
}
```

And here is the Java Code i am using to make the Request from Java Code

```
PostMethod postMethod = null;
postMethod = new PostMethod("http://localhost:9200"+"/my_index_name*/_search");
StringWriter writer = null;
try {
    String query = "{\"query\" : {" +
            "    \"bool\" : {" +
            "      \"must\" : [" +
            "        {" +
            "          \"match\" : {" +
            "            \"hashCode\" : \"7c9abf19382064fc8cea2833f4663df9813e72273ecacc8c67b5608dda1ccbab\" " +
            "            " +
            "          }" +
            "        }" +
            "      ]" +
            "    }" +
            "  }}";
    StringRequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(query,"application/json","UTF-8");

    postMethod.setDoAuthentication(true);
    postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accepts","application/json");
    postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    postMethod.setRequestEntity(entity);
    System.out.println("Request Entity =["+((StringRequestEntity)(postMethod.getRequestEntity())).getContent()+"]");

    httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
    String response = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    logger.info("Response ={}",response);
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is the log i am seeing.

```
Request Entity =[{"query" : {    "bool" : {      "must" : [        {          "match" : {            "hashCode" : "7c9abf19382064fc8cea2833f4663df9813e72273ecacc8c67b5608dda1ccbab"                       }        }      ]    }  }}]
Jul 21, 2019 11:03:20 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
Total =[0.0]
Response =[{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":0,"successful":0,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}]
```

Not sure why the response is returning zero hits..

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: can you provide your final JSON query ? also can you try running your query directly against the ES ?

Comment: When i run the curl against the ES i am getting the same response i am getting in Kibana (I am getting the actual no.of hits matching my search criteria)

Answer (score 0):

It treats spaces for json like

The double quotes and spaces and then the the \"  So the query will not be correct json the best you can do is have your query in on single line without any spaces.

Comment: No having the entire json in a single line made no difference. Also if the JSON is not valid ES should return an error rather than returning zero records.